# Need to create a column that counts values in other columns across rows in dataframe in PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, count

I have following dataframe

| Category | Subcategory 1 | Subcategory 2 | Subcategory 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Category 1 | 4 | 4 | 6 |
| Category 2 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| Category 3 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

I need another column to count for each category number of values that are greater than 0. So following is my expected output

| Category | Subcategory 1 | Subcategory 2 | Subcategory 3 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Category 1 | 4 | 4 | 6 | 3 |
| Category 2 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 2 |
| Category 3 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 1 |

I have used following code, but it is giving error:

```
df= df.withColumn(
        "Count",
        reduce(add, [F.when(F.col(c) > 0, 1).otherwise(0) for c in df.columns])
    )
```

Will someone please help me with this?

Comment: Please insert the dataframe inside a code block to be better formatted so we can help you, otherwise it's a little bit difficult to understand the data.

Comment: I have reformatted my question to display the dataframe in proper way

Comment: What is the error exactly? can you share the whole code?  your code seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I was referring to an incorrect df earlier. The code works, Thank you!

```
df= df.withColumn(
        "Count",
        reduce(add, [F.when(F.col(c) > 0, 1).otherwise(0) for c in df.columns])
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Like always, there are multiple ways to tackle this scenario. Here's what I have done:

```
df.withColumn("Count", sum(F.when(F.col(col) > 0, 1).otherwise(0) for col in df.columns if col != "cat"))
```

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  cat|col_1|col_2|count|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|cat_1|    1|    9|    2|
|cat_2|    0|    2|    1|
|cat_3|   22|    5|    2|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

You can also add further checks to check each column's datatypes if in future you could have more string columns.